# Using nogil with cpdef class method in cython

Tags: parallel-processing, cython

I want to design a cdef class whose methods can be run in parallel and therefore I need to set them as `nogil`.  I see I can do this for `cdef` methods, but for some reason I cannot understand I am not allowed to do the same with `cpdef` methods.  This in particular fails

```
cdef class Test:
    cdef int i
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
    cpdef int incr(self) nogil:
        self.i += 1;
        return self.i
```

while the same with `cdef int incr` would work.  This is somewhat surprising, because in normal `cpdef` functions the `nogil` attribute is allowed:

```
cpdef int testfunc(int x) nogil:
    return x + 1
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the C code generated (omitting `nogil`) you'll see that the first thing the method does is check to see whether the it has been overridden by a Python subclass. This requires the GIL.

(Note that this can't happen for a `cdef` function since it is never known about by Python, so there is no issue there.)

Fortunately, it is easy to make it so that your Cython class cannot be subclassed and the problem goes away (it compiles fine with `nogil`):

```
cimport cython

@cython.final
cdef class Test:
    # the rest of your code is exactly the same so isn't reproduced...
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem.  I see I cannot subclass a cython.final class in cython too, but apparently I can do it in another extension module (which is probably OK for me).

Comment: I think it's more "it can't stop you from subclassing in another extension module", rather than "you can". You risk some buggy and unexpected behaviour by subclassing things that it thinks can't be, so I'd be very careful.

Comment: OK, I understand.  On a slightly unrelated topic, perhaps you can help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869945/cython-c-code-compilation-fails-with-typed-memoryviews

Comment: About your other question - I've seen similar issues before and it's a difficult problem that I don't know the answer to!